# Is WebBrowser or WindowsFormsHost supports ViewPort3D in WPF using C# if no then why?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, 3d

I developed a Windows application with 3D Animation for flipping, which code is present in my profile.Now while I am going to Browser kind of thing in it to improve my application and for Browser implementation I tried with a WebBrowser and also with a WindowsFormHost in Viewport2DVisual3D inside the ViewPort3D Control to access "http://www.google.co.in/" like web URLs from my application. But its not visible to me while I am running my application

Please anybody suggest me how to go for this....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out WPF 3D Chromium Browser : http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/08/27/wpf-3d-chromium-browser/

Answer (score 1):

ViewPort3D will allow you to render 3D content. If you want to render normal 2D content in 3D you'll need to render the 2D content to a RenderTargetBitmap, and then apply that as a texture to a polygon in your 3D model. If you just want to use 3D for flipping between views, I'd render the 2D this normally when not flipping, then just show the 3D view during the flip since the texturised version won't look as good quality due to the texture engine in the graphics processor.